# Difference between CloudKit and Key-Value Storage

Tags: ios, icloud, cloudkit, key-value-store

What is the difference between iCloud's "Key-value storage" and CloudKit?

An example scenario would be: if one were to sync a sizable array containing dictionaries, arrays, and other objects. Would the developer want to use CloudKit or Key-value storage?

Comment: A crucial difference for me was that Key-value storage it isn't supported on WatchOS, which is rarely mentioned.

Comment: @TomášKafka Interesting, did you find any informations in the documentation about it?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

CloudKit is for syncing real data records as well as assets (files).

iCloud's key-value storage is essential `NSUserDefaults` but synced across devices.

So think of it that way. If it's a simple value you might store in `NSUserDefaults`, use key-value storage. If it's actual data you might store in a plist, database, file, or core-data, use CloudKit.

Comment: Is there a limit to the size of NSUserDefaults that can be synced?

Comment: Probably but `NSUserDefaults` is only supposed to be used for tiny bits of info such as a few strings, numbers, or bools. It's not supposed to be for any "data", just preference type info.

Answer (score 11):

I just thought it might be helpful to mention that according to the [iCloud Design Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/iCloudDesignGuide/Chapters/DesigningForKey-ValueDataIniCloud.html):

> Apps may store only 1 MB of data in their key-value storage

So that may be something that one would want to take into account in deciding between CloudKit and iCloud Key-Value Storage.

In my case, for the app I'm currently working on this limitation is totally fine. However, I would imagine that in a larger project the 1 MB limit might not be sufficient. Helps to know that up front when making the decision!

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 3):

Worth noting that there are more limitations to the `iCloud Key-Value storage` than the 1MB limit per user (mentioned in other answers before).

> There are some limits to the size of data you can store:
>
> - A maximum, overall key-value store size of 1 MB (per user)
> - One key-value pair can’t be larger than 1 MB
> - You can’t store more than 1024 key-value pairs
> - A key can’t be larger than 64 bytes using UTF-8 encoding

Comment: And it isn't supported on WatchOS, which is rarely mentioned.

Comment: @TomášKafka what do u use on WatchOS? Do you just store everything in CloudKit?

Comment: Available since watchOS 9. https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/714826